# Python Test inheritance with multiple subclasses

Tags: python, unit-testing, inheritance, subclass, python-unittest

I would like to write a Python test suite in a way that allows me to inherit from a single TestBaseClass and subclass it multiple times, everytime changing some small detail in its member variables.

Something like:

```
import unittest

class TestBaseClass(unittest.TestCase):

  def setUp(self):
    self.var1 = "exampleone"

class DetailedTestOne(TestBaseClass):
  def setUp(self):
    self.var2 = "exampletwo"

  def runTest(self):
    self.assertEqual(self.var1, "exampleone")
    self.assertEqual(self.var2, "exampletwo")

class DetailedTestOneA(DetailedTestOne):
  def setUp(self):
    self.var3 = "examplethree"

  def runTest(self):
    self.assertEqual(self.var1, "exampleone")
    self.assertEqual(self.var2, "exampletwo")
    self.assertEqual(self.var3, "examplethree")

... continue to subclass at wish ...
```

In this example, DetailedTestOne inherits from TestBaseClass and DetailedTestOneA inherits from DetailedTestOne.

With the code above, I get:

```
AttributeError: 'DetailedTestOne' object has no attribute 'var1'
```

for DetailedTestOne and:

```
AttributeError: 'DetailedTestOneA' object has no attribute 'var1'
```

for DetailedTestOneA

Of course, var1, var2, var3 could be some members of a same variable declared in first instance in the TestBaseClass.

Any ideas on how to achieve such behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call the superclass implementation in your subclasses by doing, e.g., `super(DetailedTestOne, self).setUp()` from inside your `DetailedTestOne.setUp` method.

Comment: Perfect! I thought the test framework would nest setUp calls for me treating it as an `__init__`, but I was wrong.

Comment: @FrancisStraccia: Nothing special about `__init__` in this regard.  If your subclass overrides `__init__` and you want the superclass `__init__` to be called, you have to call it explicitly in the same way I showed here.